# How do I edit lubuntu-rc.xml

Tags: lubuntu, configuration

I'm new to lubuntu so please forgive me if this is a dumb question!

I've seen posts about editing .config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml (all I want to do is a couple of keybind options) but I can't find the file or the directory.  How do I find it and edit it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open PCMan.  Click View to bring down the drop down menu and check View Hidden.  Now go to ~/.config/openbox
You should see lubuntu-rc.xml
That is where it is located.
(home/your name/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml)
http://lxlinux.com/#19
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard